# How to get value and element for JQuery remote class based validation rule?

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm trying to write a rule to validate multiple dynamically added inputs using a remote lookup. I can't figure out how to get hold of the field being validated in the remote rule definition. For example:

```
$.validator.addClassRules({
    refDataAcInput: {
        remote: {
            url: "/json/refDataLookup.html",
            type: "get",
            data: {
                groupName: function(a,b,c){
                    //$(this).data("groupName");
                    //THE ABOVE DOESN'T WORK, HERE I WANT TO GET THE VALUE OF THE FIELD BEING VALIDATED
                },
                term: function(a,b,c){
                    //$(this).val();
                    //THE ABOVE DOESN'T WORK, HERE I WANT TO GET THE VALUE OF THE FIELD BEING VALIDATED
                },
                exactMatch: "true"
            },
            dataFilter: function(data, type) {
                return data;
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I really like your idea, but what you want to do can't be done using addClassRules as it is now.  The problem isn't really with jQuery Validate, but more with how jQuery.ajax works when generating your data.  Those functions in the data object are not called with a context (i.e. so that `this` is filled as you expect).  The jQuery code looks something like this:

```
value = jQuery.isFunction( value ) ? value() : value;
```

I believe that makes sense, because of the way that $.ajax is generally used, it would have access to local variables such that this wouldn't matter (i.e. before calling $.ajax, you would have simply created the data object you wanted).  For the the case of Validate, your only option may be to use the data provided by `remote`, which is the input name as the key and the input's value as the value (i.e. `fieldName:value`) and modify your remote script to deal with that.

If that isn't an option because you need your `groupName` data, you could consider editing the [source code](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/jquery.validate.js#L1024).  What I would do in that case is change this line (L1024 in github):

```
data[element.name] = value;
```

To this:

```
data = $(element).data();
data[element.name] = value;
```

Which would push any `jQuery.data` values attached to your element into your ajax request.